# Js can read cookies but can't evaluate them

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, colors, background

I have made a webpage that asks user's that if they want to enable an effect, if they say yes then i store that "YES" as a cookie `effect=true` or if they don't want it then i also store it as `effect=false` cookie. The problem is listed as steps below:

1. User visits a webpage (first time)
2. He is alerted with `document.cookie` which is "".
3. He Clicks OK
4. Now value of `saveedd` is "", So according to my code the code below `// Checkpoint 2` Should execute as value of saved is neither `true` nor `false`.
5. But instead It executes only 1 line of code below `// Checkpoint 1` , This should not happen as value of `saveed` is not `false`.

What am I doing Wrong?

Note : I have stripped some code, So if you find any mistakes like `var` not defined ,Please comment

## index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Second Page</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="askk()">
    </body>

    </html>
```

## script.js

```
function askk() {
    var saveedd = getCookie('effect');
    alert(saveedd);
    if (saveedd == true) {
        changge();
        alert('i wil change');
    } else if (saveedd == false) {
         // Checkpoint 1
        alert('i will not change'); 
    } else {
          // Checkpoint 2
        document.cookie = "effect=;expires=Wed; 01 Jan 1970";
        var z = confirm("Enable Bgcolor Effect?");
        if (z) {
            changge();
        }
        setCookie("effect", z, 30);
    }

}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 30);
        }
    }
}

function changge() {
    window.setInterval("Farbe()", 500);
}
farbe = 1;

function Farbe() {
    if (farbe == 1) {
        document.bgColor = "indigo";
        farbe = 2;
    } else if (farbe == 2) {
        document.bgColor = "red";
        farbe = 3;
    } else if (farbe == 3) {
        document.bgColor = "green";
        farbe = 4;
    } else if (farbe == 4) {
        document.bgColor = "blue";
        farbe = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any javascript error at the console?

Comment: @MayankSharma No, No browser's console window shows any error.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: @MayankSharma Sure, http://jsfiddle.net/qyfprp48/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comparison `if (saveedd == false)` string `saveedd` casting to bool type, empty string in JS casting to `false`. You should compare string with string like this: `(saveedd == 'false')`

Comment: Now its ok, but even if the cookie reads `true` its not executing `alert('i wil change');`

Comment: Just put `true` in quotes `(saveedd == 'true')`. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qyfprp48/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing with the == operator, which coerces variables to be the same type before comparison. Hence, the value saveedd, which is the empty string '' will be converted to false.  This is why Checkpoint 1 is being executed.

You will need to compare using the triple equals ===. This will preserve the type of the variables you are comparing, so saveedd == false will only be true if saveedd is false, not 0, '', [] or another "falsy" value. See [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for more information.

Edit:

As weeklyTea mentions, you are also comparing against the boolean true and false. You may need to compare against the strings "true" and "false" instead.

Comment: Now its ok, but even if the cookie reads `true` its not executing `alert('i wil change');`

Comment: See edit - you may need to compare against the strings.